# how to host code on Google code or any other site

Tags: github, google-code

I'm looking for any website that could host my codes to be accessed from any where for example I want to save "example.css" on that site and then I should able to include that "example.css" in my pages. I already have a Google code account but it's not linking my code.

If it is possible please explain in detailed way.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not linking my code"?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think the system will allow him to comment without a bit more rep. I just assumed he was linking the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In google code, go to your project, click the "source" tab and then the "browse" link. Find the CSS file you want to link to. Click the "View raw file" link on the right side. This will pull up the raw version of the file. Copy the address out of the URL bar and use it to link your stylesheets.

For example, look at [this google code project](http://code.google.com/p/hartija/).

Click "source," "browse," "trunk," and "print.css" to get [here](http://code.google.com/p/hartija/source/browse/trunk/print.css).

Now click "view raw file" to get [here](http://hartija.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/print.css).

If you're using SVN, you can also set the MIME type of the file to the appropriate type, but it's not strictly necessary; most browsers will know what to do. Git doesn't allow you to specify MIME types.